# Can a JWT fit in a 1D barcode?

Tags: jwt, authorization, compression

Many APIs use JWTs to Authorize requests. 1D barcodes seem to be able to hold ~20-128 ASCII characters. An example JWT I have is 300 characters long.

What characterset do JWTs use? Could you compress a JWT to fit in 128 ASCII characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can produce a [JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (signed JWT) with less than 128 characters, but I don't know if this fits on a 1D barcode

The claims described in [rfc7519, section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4) are all optional, so you can limit yourself to one or two claims.

The 3 segments of a JWS (header, payload, signature) are [base64url](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) encoded, which uses basically a limited subset of the ASCII character set.

A HS256 signature is also quite short.

Here is an example that I produced on https://jwt.io:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEyMzQ1NjciLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9.5MUB9gKEULAzH1iQhOTw_0hMx92LC5tM-f-0udDws38
```

This is just 126 characters long.

You can paste the example token to the debugger window on https://jwt.io to see what's inside.

With an online barcode generator I made this barcode. Not sure if this is really useable, it probably depends on the software you use to read it:

[image: a JWT as 1D barcode]

A QR-Code might be a better idea in this case.