# How to make JWT smaller like Discord does?

Tags: jwt

I was wondering how I can to make JWT with length of 235 characters small like Discord's

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you give an example of the Discord token? Where do you get your JWTs from? Do you issue them yourself?

Comment: @Michal Trojanowski Yes, I issue them using PHP package firebase/php-jwt, Here's example of Discord token: `Nzg1NDE3MzEzNzM3NjM3OTM4.X83i3w.OTOyP3JS79MKvrHL_EVvxaNxp5M`, that token contains user ID, account creation date and HMAC. [Details](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6506416/81051916-dd8c9900-8ec2-11ea-8794-daf12d6f31f0.png)

Comment: for whatever reason you need this,  you can create a minimal JWT with just 120 to 130 bytes, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699169/can-a-jwt-fit-in-a-1d-barcode. But keep in mind that the Discord example you have shown is no JWT and JWT has some overhead because it has a header and it uses JSON.

Comment: As jps says, that example from Discord is not a JWT. It's just a token which happens to look a bit similar to a JWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a JWT depends on the amount of data which is in the header and payload. The more data you have in the payload, the longer the resulting token will be. So you can somewhat control the length of the token. Normally this should not be a problem for you if the token is longer or shorter.

Comment: The sample JWT on jwt.io has 155 characters using a jwt.SigningMethodHS256 and payload of `{"sub": "1234567890","name": "John Doe","iat": 1516239022}`. Add a couple more fields and it will be 235.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const payload = {
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true,
  "iat": "1643202358"
};

const secret = 'SecKey';

// creates the token

const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret);
console.log(token);

// verifies the token

const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret);
console.log(decoded);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).